# xampp - no longer loads local website but always redirects to internet version of site

Tags: xampp

I have a website that is live and a version that I am working on locally using `XAMPP`. For some reason every time I try to load:

```
http://localhost/websitename
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1/websitename
```

it goes to the internet version. This has only started happening. All services are started. XAMPP is working for all other sites that I am working on locally.

Comment: Any hard-coded url? or redirects?

Comment: How stupid have I been - yes a hard coded redirect but had not realised I had been logged out, causing the redirect. Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and should be on webmasters or some other stack exchange site.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths, I will move my comment to an answer for others that might see the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Check your site settings as I believe you're having the url in your website set to the live version.

Comment: Thanks - all sorted. A stupid error on my part. See above. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can have alot of reasons.

What does your windows host file have for redirect rules (C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/host) I assume that you use Windows because you said "xampp", correct me if im wrong)

Check for header(); redirects within your websites php scripts.

Do you have a v-host entry redirecting you to another url in your v-host config of your apache?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any **hard-coded url's**? or **redirects**? in the project that are redirecting to the live version.